# iPhone Use UIImagePickerController to capture selective frames from a video

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, video-processing

I wanted to use the UiImagePicker to record a video then let the user browse the frames using the scrollview built in the UiImagePicker and while at it, select a few frames that interest the user.

I know I can overlay a control on top of the uiimagepicker to trigger the selection

What I am not sure about is whether I have programatic access to the current frame shown by the UIImagePicker for me to extract an image out of it.

Please let me know if this is doable/possible.

Are there any other time efficient/elegant ways to achieving the above?

I had created by own view with video recording and frame selection (using AVCaptureSession, AVCaptureVideoDataOutput) but would take me quite a bit of time to polish it to make it look good like UIImagePicker plus everyone is familiar with the default camera app in the iPhone.

I hope it makes sense what I want to achieve.

I know one can kind of achieve the goal by taken a screenshot of the screen but I just want the user to click one button to capture the current show frame.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screenshot method did not work for frozen frame from the video recording.

Went with a custom AVFoundation based frame capture.